# Display all the files with read and write permissions and display result in a file

Tags: 14.04, permissions, files, ls

I need to display all the files with read and write permissions and save the result in a file.
Can anybody help me with that?

It's easy but I am little bit confused, so please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the `find` command.

```
find /path/to/where/to/search -type f -perm -666
```

Enter path where you want to do the search. The `-type f` meand that only files will be searched. Finally `-perm 666` means that only files with read/write permissions for all users will be matched. Please note that if file has also executable permission for any user it will not be matched. Than you just redirect the output to a file:

```
find /path/to/where/to/search -type f -perm -666 > LogFile.txt
```

Read [man pages for find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to learn more and to realy match the permissions for users/grup you really need.