# Find files based on permission

Tags: command-line, permissions, find

How can I find a list of files that have some specific permissions?

I want to find files owned by `root` user that have `rwx` permission for the owner.

Is there any way to find a list of such files? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Is this helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/786347/display-all-the-files-with-read-and-write-permissions-and-display-result-in-a-fi/786352#786352

Answer (score 23):

Yes, GNU `find` can do it:

> -user uname
>
> > File is owned by user uname (numeric user ID allowed).
>
> -perm -mode
>
> > All of the permission bits mode are set for the file.   Symbolic
> >               modes  are accepted in this form, and this is usually the way in
> >               which you would want to use them.  You must specify 'u', 'g'  or
> >               'o'  if  you use a symbolic mode.   See the EXAMPLES section for
> >               some illustrative examples.

So, you want:

```
find /path/to/directory -user root -perm -u+rwx
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find all files a user has certain permission for (regardless if he is the owner (and even set via ACL)) you can use `find` with `-readable`, `-writable` and `-executable`.

To find all files for which user *sam* has read-permission

```
sudo -u sam find /path/to/directory -readable -ls
```

- `sudo -u sam` is needed because the three mentioned switches work with the permissions of the user that invoked `find` - so you need sudo to run `find` as user *sam*.
- `-ls` shows the complete entry for each file found

---

further examples
To find all files for which *sam* has `execute` **or** `write` permissions

```
sudo -u sam find /path/to/directory -writable -or -executable -ls
```

To find all files for which *sam* has `execute` **and** `read` permissions

```
sudo -u sam find /path/to/directory -readable -and -executable -ls
```

<sub>writable is **not** misspelled!</sub>